# Store temp data on Express Server vs. keep using SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, socket.io

I'm creating a socket io application that has many rooms and many users inside of these rooms. I needed a way to store temp data about the room and its users. (socketio can store data about each socket connection but not the room) I thought about using a HashMap on the server (key: room) => (val: tempData) but thought that would be too much overhead for Node.JS since it's single-threaded. So, I decided to just store temp data in a Postgres table. Temp data get added and deleted often. There are a few boolean values, etc.

The essence of my question: Is it okay for me to store temp data on Postgres or would it be better to just store it in a HashMap on Express Server?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer depends on whether you need the data to survive a reboot of the nodejs server. If you need persistent data, choose the DBMS over RAM data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 1 server then keep it in memory

If you have more than 1 server OR want the data to stick around if the server is restarted hold it in the DB